# Shell script for creating user with password in postgres failing with quotes

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell

I am trying to create a shell script to bootstrap new DBs. 
I am able to create users, grant privileges and do all actions, except running any queries with passwords. The single quotes in shell script creates statements which postgres is not accepting.
Because of this, we cannot completely automate this process.

Below is one of the postgres line used in shell script.

```
PGPASSWORD=change123 psql -h $DB -p 5432 -d postgres -U root -c \"CREATE USER $(echo "$j" | cut -d "_" -f1)dbuser WITH PASSWORD \'$(echo $DBPASSWD|base64 --decode)\';\"
```

When executing the above script, the command is converted as

```
psql -h testdb -p 5432 -d postgres -U root -c '"CREATE' USER admindbuser WITH PASSWORD ''\''ZnuLEmu72R'\'''
```

where I want the command to be like

```
psql -h testdb -p 5432 -d postgres -U root -c "CREATE USER admindbuser WITH PASSWORD 'ZnuLEmu72R';"
```

Any help is very much appreciated. I want some help in guiding how to modify the line in shell so as to achieve the required command.

Comment: Please remove all four backslashes and try again.

Comment: Why do you have a backslash before the initial double quotes?

Comment: ...mind you, doing this *securely* (in a way that doesn't let someone choosing a malicious password run an arbitrary database command) is a whole different question. If that's something you'd consider important, I'd suggest amending the question to make it clear.

Comment: @thriqon tried it already and its failing like below
```psql -h testdb -p 5432 -d postgres -U root -c 'CREATE USER admindbuser WITH PASSWORD '\''1k4a24ILvzJqT'\'';'
```

Comment: @yograj, nothing about what you quoted in the comment immediately above this one is obviously wrong. The bare quotes are shell syntax, the escaped ones are literal content passed to `psql`. Try running `printf '%s\n' psql -h testdb -p 5432 -d postgres -U root -c 'CREATE USER admindbuser WITH PASSWORD '\''1k4a24ILvzJqT'\'';' ` and you'll see a list of arguments passed one-per-line as psql actually receives them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the DBnames or password given here is not the exact one. regarding the root password, once its working, I will start storing it in encrypted way.

Comment: That misses my point (about security risk). You're creating passwords for users, right? If the users are able to choose the passwords, they could pick a password with something like `'; INSERT INTO TABLE admins ROWS(whatever); --` as part of it, and instead of being set as part of their password, that (or something like it) could run a hostile query that user isn't supposed to be able to run.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy this for the apps to do a intial bootstrap and not for users.

Comment: By the way, why not use `createuser` instead of `psql`?

Comment: @yograj, ...regardless, it still introduces risk to have injection bugs, because it requires you to trust that initial-bootstrap code in a way that (because of the base64-encoding) can't be audited at a glance. It's always a bad thing if your codebase has places someone could slip in a vulnerability that wouldn't be obvious to a reviewer reading the diff.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
PGPASSWORD=change123 psql\
  -h $DB \
  -p 5432 \
  -d postgres \
  -U root \
  -c \"CREATE USER $(echo "$j" | cut -d "_" -f1)dbuser WITH PASSWORD \'$(echo $DBPASSWD|base64 --decode)\';\"
```

to

```
PGPASSWORD=change123 psql \
  -h "$DB" \
  -p 5432 \
  -d postgres \
  -U root \
  -c "CREATE USER ${j%%_*}dbuser WITH PASSWORD '$(printf '%s' "$DBPASSWD" | base64 --decode)';"
```

Comment: Only caveat here is that this doesn't take any effort to move the data out-of-band from the (SQL) code. (After all, if all the users we were setting passwords for were completely trusted, they could just be given a shared admin account).

Comment: Even using, say, `sql_str() { printf "'%s'" "${1//\'/''}"; }` and substituting in `$(sql_str "$(base64 --decode --ignore-garbage <<<"$DBPASSWD")` is better than no escaping at all.

Comment: bash -x gives below output for the above changes.
`
+ PGPASSWORD=change123
+ psql -h testdb -p 5432 -d postgres -U root -c 'CREATE USER admindbuser WITH PASSWORD '\''xWb0HL3CmG0dfXWY8e'\'';'
`

Comment: @yograj, yes, and that's *correct* `bash -x` output; it's how your command is *supposed* to be run. Once you strip out the quotes that are shell syntax instead of SQL syntax (as with the `printf '%s\n'` trick I showed you in the question's comments), you're left with a query of `CREATE USER admindbuser WITH PASSWORD 'xWb0HL3CmG0dfXWY8e';`, and that query is what you want.

Comment: @yograj, ...as an explanation of why the shell has the extra single-quotes that don't look like they make sense to you, keep in mind that backslashes are literal inside single-quotes, so when it prints ```'\"```, what it's doing is first exiting the single-quoted context that was entered into earlier, then creating a backslashed (thus literal) double-quote character.

Comment: @yograj, ...see https://ideone.com/k6DcG5 for the aforementioned one-argument-per-line printout of how the command in question actually resolves to an argv array passed to `psql`.